# Сортировка по весу

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, сортировка

Надо написать функцию, которая сортирует список положительных чисел.
Критерий сортировки - возрастание веса числа (сумма всех цифр числа).
Если два числа имеют одинаковый вес, сортировать их так, словно они строки.

Я попытался решить эту задачу следующим образом:

```
import traceback

 num_weight = lambda x: sum(int(i) for i in str(x))

  def order_weight(integers):
      for i in range(len(integers)-1):
          if num_weight(integers[i]) < num_weight(integers[i+1]):
              integers.sort(key=num_weight)
          elif num_weight(integers[i]) == num_weight(integers[i+1]):
              sorted(integers)
      print(integers)
      return integers


  # Тесты
  try:
      assert order_weight([103, 123, 4444, 99, 2000]) 
                         == [2000, 103, 123, 4444, 9    9]
      assert order_weight([2000, 10003, 1234000, 44444444, 9999, 11, 11, 22, 123]    ) ==             
                          [11, 11, 2000, 10003, 22, 123, 1234000, 44444444, 9999]
  except AssertionError:
      print("TEST ERROR")
      traceback.print_exc()
  else:
      print("TEST PASSED")
```

Чем можно заменить функцию `sorted()` в строке `elif num_weight(integers[i])...`,
чтобы сортировка элементов с одинаковыми весами как сортировка строк выполнялась верно?

Вот вывод программы при использовании функции `sorted()`:

```
[2000, 103, 123, 4444, 99]
[2000, 11, 11, 10003, 22, 123, 1234000,44444444, 9999]
TEST ERROR
Traceback (most recent call last): File "task489.py", line 28, in <module>
assert
order_weight([2000, 10003, 1234000, 44444444, 9999, 11, 11, 22, 123])
== [11, 11, 2000, 10003, 22, 123, 1234000, 44444444, 9999]*
AssertionError
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё проще, `sorted` может принимать `tuple` в качестве ключа сортировки и таким образом мы можем сортировать сразу по нескольким ключам одновременно:

```
def order_weight(integers):
    return sorted(integers, key = lambda x: (sum(int(i) for i in str(x)), str(x)))
```

Результат:

```
TEST PASSED
```

Comment: Хорошее решение, в одну строчку, быстрое, я например поторопился и складывал элементы из строки с резульатом в отдельный массив целых чисел и подавал его на выход, результат программа приняла, но решение стало хуже тем, что при больших массивах производительность такой программы снижается.

Comment: @OstapBender Для больших массивов, кстати, можно даже ещё ускорить, если числа в списке часто повторяются. Для этого надо вынести подсчёт tuple из lambda в отдельную функцию и повесить на эту функцию декоратор lru_cache :)

Answer (score 2):

Python использует стабильный алгоритм сортировки, поэтому можно сначала отсортировать список как строки. После этого можно сортировать полученный список по сумме цифр:

```
def order_weight(integers):
    res = sorted([str(x) for x in integers])
    res = sorted(res, key=lambda x: sum(int(d) for d in x))
    return res
```

Comment: писал с телефона, поэтому код не тестировал

Comment: Так не сработает же. Вторая сортировка никак не учтёт первую.

Comment: А, нет, сработало таки, только в виде строк всё стало в результате.

Comment: @CrazyElf, согласен, плохое решение